# android TYPE_PHONE vs TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT

Tags: android

What is the difference between using one or the other?

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams windowManagerParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, //WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            windowManagerFlags,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the [Android Developer reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html) for the `WindowManager.LayoutParams`:

> **Window type: phone**. These are non-application windows providing user interaction with the phone (in particular incoming calls). These windows are normally placed above all applications, but behind the status bar. In multiuser systems shows on all users' windows. ([TYPE_PHONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_PHONE))
>
> **Window type: system window**, such as low power alert. These windows are always on top of application windows. In multiuser systems shows only on the owning user's window. ([TYPE_SYSTEM_WINDOW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT))

So it depends on the use case and on the environment (multi-user, single-user, one specific user)

Answer (score 0):

One of differences is how to deal with `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN` and `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE`.

Starting from API 19 options `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN` and `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE` [don't affect](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/81479358decb0a2cefbb8245e0f56ed0e966d697/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindowManager.java#3280) windows with types `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` and `TYPE_TOAST` ([and TYPE_VOLUME_OVERLAY for API 21 and 22](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ca4d040%5E!/); in API 23 `TYPE_VOLUME_OVERLAY` removed from this list).

It is all about `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`.

`TYPE_PHONE` act normally with `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN` and `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE`.